# What are n-tier architecture scope in web-application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, n-tier-architecture

I've found out n-Tier web application concept like following categories:

1-  Database (including database business and table or store procedures and all database stuff)

2-  Web. Data (including entities and repositories)

3-  Web. Model (including not entities some simple model can transfer to client)

4-  Web. Business (in some application is admitted it is not mandatory but it includes some functionality such as how to calculates things)

5-  Web. Service (including web API on SOAP restful application)

6-  Web. Security (it includes some custom security as you wish but it is not mandatory)

7-  Web. Client (including client-side functionalities like jquery, mvvm and some other like  authentication, securities implemented in UI)

8-  Web. Extension (including extra helper methods and wrapper objects)

9-  Web. Handler (including all handler and modules)

These layers could be placed on different projects they could be implemented by MVC or even by asp.net of course with the same concept.

I was wondering if my understanding was right or not? or got any better idea? Could you expand them more or are they limited and enough?

Please guide me what are standards about them?

Comment: You can find help at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/430014/N-Tier-Architecture-and-Tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look MyPrettyCMS Framework in codeplex ?

It's exactely that...

https://myprettycms.codeplex.com

In the next release, it includes Web API and Web API OData Handling.

If you want to follow the developer group, find the Linked in group : myPrettyCMS Happy Contributors Associates

Answer (score 1):

N-tier concept is wider than just listing the exact tiers. This concept helps to divite your application to manageble and isolated levels, which you could change, re-design, substitute without breaking and re-writing the entire application. The number of tiers could vary depending on technology stack you use.

read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture

Answer (score 0):

You should try looking into the XWA architecture if your primary concern is web applications.
http://madeyski.e-informatyka.pl/download/23.pdf

XWA architecture builds atop the concepts know from the MVC and PCMEF.